# How to handle valid missing values in a classification problem?

Tags: classification, missing-data

I would like to predict a binary output based on borrower's informations in a bank credit demand/file.

My problem is that this file can be filled either by

1. a single borrower (celibate)
2. or 2 borrowers (couple)

My dataset looks like this:

nb_of_B | B1_Info1 | ... | B1_InfoN | B2_Info1 | ... | B2_InfoN

(B means Borrower, and I have about N = 15 informations for each borrower)

Then, I have automatically **normal missing values** in B2_InfoX variables in the case of there is just 1 borrower (nb_of_B = 1).

I've found many posts on how to interpolate/impute missing data but in this case, it would not make any sense!

So my question is: **Which classification algorithm can handle theses normal missing values?**

Do I have to find a workaround? like making 2 models, one for the case nb_of_B = 1, the other for the case nb_of_B = 2?

Any other solution?

How can we **generalize** this type of problem for a bigger situation, like files with potentially **10 borrowers**? (10 is the limit and I don't expect it to increase)

For information, the number of files decrease drastically as the number of borrowers exceed 2 borrowers and I cannot make a unique model for the case of 10 borrowers because there is too few files to learn. Below is the distribution:

1 borrower -> 62,57%, 2 borrower -> 36.48%, ... 10 borrowers -> 0,0015% so 99% of my files fall into 1 or 2 borrowers

Thanks for your answers,

Mat

Comment: do you know the max no of borrowers possible ? i mean like is 10 the limit or do you expect it to increase ?

Comment: In this case, 10 is the limit and I don't expect it to increase. but to give you more insight, it's distributed like this.
1 borrower -> 62,57%, 2 borrower -> 36.48%, ... 10 borrowers -> 0,0015%
so 99% of my files fall into 1 or 2 borrowers

Comment: Would be good to edit your question to include the extra information from your comment.

Comment: That's right. It's done. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well , it would make sense if you do some intelligent feature engineering-that way you have a single model for all.

For example if you have salary of the person as a feature you could use two features - total salary (sum of the salaries) and average salary (maybe drop one, like average ). All the while keeping the num borrowers as a feature in itself.

You should think of it this way does an increased total salary necessarily help you to predict or not ? you could also extract other statistics but keep in mind what makes sense for the problem. This could be a good starting point.

Why, Im suggesting this is because we have done something like this in the medical domain for example when using patient reading's for diagnosis. In our case the number of readings per patient varied drastically ... um well you can figure that each patient stays for a different duration. Hand engineered Statistical features (mean ,median,mode) and interpolation of missing values worked best for us... Interpolation doesn't make sense in your case ,Im hopeful that statistical features will work for you .

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vaibhav.
'Well , it would make sense if you do some intelligent feature engineering-that way you have a single model for all.' Yes that's the strategy I would primary like to follow. For quantitative variable, I've already done some feature-engineering like you say. What about categorical data like "socio-professional category" (40 modalities)? any Idea to "aggregate" this kind of data for every borrower in an intelligent way?

Comment: one idea that comes to mind is to consider modalities as a collection of words effectively forming a document for each sample.This way each sample becomes a document. use one-hot, tf-idf. eg your document :-[1,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] for two borrowers in case one is a banker(1) and second is  doctor(12). then onehot this.you will have to experiment with what works . Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: Yes, very good idea!
I'll try to implement it. Thx!